# React how to concat an Anchor element (a tag) to string

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, anchor

I am trying to show

```
        {`I agree to the ${(
          <a href={termsFile} download>
            Terms and Conditions
          </a>
        )}`}
```

but the text shows up as "I agree to the [object Object]" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
<>
  I agree to the{" "}
  <a href={termsFile} download>
    Terms and Conditions
  </a>
</>
```

If you write it down in a single line you don't need the `{" "}`, you can use a normal space:

```
<>
  I agree to the <a>Terms</a>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your JSX element you can try something like this

```
    <>
      I agree to the {(
      <a href={termsFile} download>
        Terms and Conditions
      </a>
    )}
   </>
```